# Is there a minimum size for aws s3 sync to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to move the contents from the S3 bucket I have been using up until now (src-bucket) to a new S3 bucket within a new AWS account (dst-bucket). As far as I can tell, the straight forward approach would be

`aws s3 sync s3://src-bucket s3://dst-bucket --exclude "*" --include="important_prefix*"`

But this only works a bit. For a subset of objects I keep getting the error message

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied
```

and I cannot find the reason why.

So far I can tell that all the files that cannot be synced are rather small (less than 700kb) while the successfully copied ones are at least a couple of MB each.

Is there some minimum object size (with a relatively high default value) that must be met before `s3 sync` can do its work?

---

More information

- I can perfectly `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3api get-object` the problematic objects. They just fail with `aws s3 sync`.
- In both accounts I have a user with `S3FullAccess` permissions
- I added the following bucket policy to src-bucket

  ```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "Example permissions",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::newaccountid:user/myadminuser"
    },
    "Action": [
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::src-bucket"
  },
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::newaccountid:user/myadminuser"
    },
    "Action": [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::src-bucket/*"
  }
  ]
  }
  ```

  - I run `aws s3 sync` as the newaccountid:user/myadminuser

I can browse around `src-bucket` with the user from the new account and I can upload and download files just fine. Running the initially mentioned `aws s3 sync` command copies a few 100 objects from `src-bucket` to `dst-bucket`, but fails for some other hundrets of objects.

I tried comparing the not-sync-able objects to those that I was able to sync successfully. I did a `aws s3api get-object-acl` on many objects in `src-bucket`. Their ACLs all look the same, for successfully copied ones and copy-failed ones:

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "reallylongidihadbashcomparethemformetomakesuretheyareidentical"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "CanonicalUser",
                "ID": "reallylongidihadbashcomparethemformetomakesuretheyareidentical"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

On `dst-bucket` the really long id is a different one, but apart from that the ACLs look the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such thing. I was correlating the wrong things. Apparently `s3 sync` "depends" on being able to copy the objects' tags, as well as their data. Reading objects' tags is a separate privilege from reading the objects data. I was missing the `s3:GetObjectTagging` action when granting rights to my new user.

Apparently "they" started splitting data into much smaller chunks at the same time they started using object tags.